# Handling focus with react-select

Tags: reactjs, react-select, rc-slider

I'm trying to figure out how to work around what appears to be greedy-focus issues with `react-select`.

I'm using custom components in my `MenuList` component that need the focus to work (`rc-slider`). Basically, I'd like the select to support an additional value for each `option` and I'm using a `Slider` to do that.

[image]

The issue with the sliders is that I can click on them to change the value, but can't drag the handles, as the `Select` seems to take back the focus (and even close the drop-down if `menuIsOpen` is not controlled).

The select does need to re-render when the values change, but I can't figure out why the focus has to change.

https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-moon-cv33b

Comment: Wait but why do you need sliders inside (!) Select? I mean it is not even good UI, Select suppose to select from list, no? Sorry, I know that it is not an answer, but just to clarify what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Totally fair question, @VladislavSorokin - I'm using this in conjunction with several other `Select` components, and I thought this would be the easiest way to keep the looks consistent. Most of the functionality is the same, with the pull-down, the selected items displayed as chips, and the "x" to remove. Keys with values of 0 would indicate they aren't selected. I am using a workaround here that mimics the look/feel, but I thought this would reduce duplication.

Comment: @jamstooks I'm having exactly the same issue. Did you manage to solve it?